How to export a gt table with embedded plots into a MS-Word file?
I generated a gt table with embedded plots. Please refer to the following pic

We plan to use this table for our manuscript. Since the target journal only accepts table in MS Word file, I tried to export this table to a .docx file. However, neither gtsave() nor as_word() did not work. I meant, both two functions could write the contents into a .docx file, but the plots were not shown, and the .docx file look like the following pic

